# Flutter: Cloud Firestore serverTimestamp() doubles document reads

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, timestamp

When creating a new Cloud Firestore document with a field `"timestamp"` containing a `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, the document at first gets uploaded with the value `null` in the `"timestamp"` field and then it will be set to the actual value, this means if I am subscribing on this collection I double my document reads, is there a workaround? Should it be like that?

Here's the code and the console log:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyStream(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStream extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStreamState createState() => _MyStreamState();
}

class _MyStreamState extends State<MyStream> {

  int id = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("docs").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting || !snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data==null){
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              print("----------------------------- NEW SNAPSHOT -----------------------------");
              for(DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.data.documents){
                print(ds.data);
              }
              return Flexible(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: snapshot.data.documents.map(_docUI).toList(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: (){
                  Firestore.instance.collection("docs").document().setData({"id" : ++id, "timestamp" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onPressed: (){
                  Firestore.instance.collection("docs").getDocuments().then((snap){
                    for(DocumentSnapshot ds in snap.documents){
                      ds.reference.delete();
                    }
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _docUI(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return Center(child: Text(doc.data["timestamp"].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  The first read is not billed, because it's coming from local cache.

Comment: Thank you! Does the first read also include the documents that already has been there? So that they are also not billed?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Perhaps post another question to explain.